# What does the "type" attribute of a directive do?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What does the "type" attribute of a directive do? I can't seem to find it documented.

Here's an example of its usage: 
https://github.com/crudbetter/angular-charts/blob/master/src/piechart.js#L81

Does that usage just create an unused attribute, or does it actually have some sort of meaning?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile The name of the property is the more precise `templateNamespace` since 1.3.0-beta.19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type` attribute governs how the template is wrapped. Specifically, if it is `svg` or `math` it is wrapped in a `div` and a sub element of the type. Here is the function that leverages it inside the $compile service where the directive API lives [from the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js):

```
function wrapTemplate(type, template) {
  type = lowercase(type || 'html');
  switch (type) {
  case 'svg':
  case 'math':
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.innerHTML = '<' + type + '>' + template + '</' + type + '>';
    return wrapper.childNodes[0].childNodes;
  default:
    return template;
  }
}
```

It's now known as `templateNamespace`, and described as such in the docs.

Comment: I think that's what `templateNamespace` is used for.

Comment: +1 I wonder if the usage linked was actually a typo, or a hangover from an older version?

Comment: Yeah, there's no mention to any of them prior to v1.3.*

Comment: Maybe a typo... it's worth investigating though

Comment: It's a bit of a smoking gun that the internal `wrapTemplate` method's parameter name is `type`. That's how I got there anyway.

Comment: Well, I couldn't make it work with either `type` or `templateNamespace`. Here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tivie/p2vp8hv1/). Angular v1.3.2

Comment: Looking at the source, it seems the effect is only visible in certain conditions, such as when `replace:true` (now deprecated) and a `templateUrl` are being used.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the [AngularJS Directive Definition Object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object) documentation goes, there is no mention to a "type" attribute whatsoever.

In the source you provided, they use the value 'SVG'. The only related attribute would be `templateNamespace` which corresponds to the document type used by the markup in the template.

AngularJS needs this information as those elements need to be created and cloned in a special way when they are defined outside their usual containers like `<svg>` and `<math>`.

---

**Edit:**

Well, I tried finding out if `type` works like `templateNamespace` but couldn't make any of them work (tried with Angular v1.3.2 and v1.2.1).

here's the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tivie/p2vp8hv1/)**

Comment: Yes, now called templateNamespace.